# Formatting lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a function that takes inputs of lists from the user and returns them as such:

```
>>> print_table([[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,4,9,16,25],[0,1,8,27,64,125]])
0   1   2   3   4   5   
0   1   4   9   16  25  
0   1   8   27  64  125 
>>> print_table(times_table(6,6))
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   
0   2   4   6   8   10  12  
0   3   6   9   12  15  18  
0   4   8   12  16  20  24  
0   5   10  15  20  25  30  
0   6   12  18  24  30  36
```

The times_table refers to my current code:

```
def times_table(s):
    n = int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
    for row in range(n+1):
        s = ''
        for col in range(n+1):
                s += '{:3} '.format(row * col)
        print(s)
```

Help me if you can....

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: I dont know how to take tuples as inputs as well as formatting the output like the example

Comment: It is not clear what your final goal is, but you might want to look at `numpy` and `pandas`. For example, your `times_table` can be created using `numpy.outer` and `pandas` provides nice options for pretty printing.

Answer (score 1):

To get two values as input from the user, i.e. number of columns and rows, you can do as follows:

```
in_values = input('Please enter two positive integers between 1 and 15, separated by comma (e.g. 2,3): ')
m,n =  map(int, in_values.split(','))
print(m,n)
```

Answer (score 1):

To print out a formatted list of lists, you may wish to consider using string formatting through the format() method of strings.  One thing I notice in your upper example is that you only get to 3 digits, and the space between the numbers seems to be unchanging.  For lists with large numbers, this will likely mess up the formatting of the table.  By using the format() method, you can take this into account and keep your table nicely spaced.

The easiest way I can think of to accomplish this is to determine what is the single largest number (most digits) in the entire list of lists and then incorporate that in the formatting.  I would recommend you read up on string formatting for the python type string (including the mini formatting language).

Assuming s is the argument passed in to print_table:

```
maxchars = len(str(max(max(s))))
```

This will provide the largest number of characters in a single entry in the list. You can then utilize this number in the formatting of the rows in a for loop:

```
for lst in l:
        output = ""
        for i in lst:
            output += "{0:<{1}} ".format(i, maxchars)
        print(output)
```

the line output += "{0:<{1}} ".format(i, maxchars) means to print the number ({0} maps to the i in the call to format) left adjusted (<) in a space of characters "maxchars" wide ({1} maps to maxchars in the call to format).

So given your list of lists above, it will print it as:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   
0   1   4   9   16  25  
0   1   8   27  64  125
```

but if the numbers are much larger (or any of the numbers are much larger, such as the 125 being replaced with 125125, it will unfortunately look like this because it is padding each item with the appropriate number of character spaces to contain a number of 6 characters:

```
0      1      2      3      4      5      
0      1      4      9      16     25     
0      1      8      27     64     125125
```

The above example takes a variable number of characters into account, however you could also format the string using an integer by replacing the {1} with an integer and omitting the maxchars portion (including both setting it and it being passed to format) if that is sufficient.

```
output += "{0:<4} ".format(i)
```

Optionally, you could figure out how to determine the largest number in a given column and then just format that column appropriately, however I am not going to put that in this answer.

Comment: Actually, it might be better to instead append each formatted string to a list and then just print the joined final string.  I am bad about using join, so I always overlook it.  Anyone have any thoughts about changing output from a string to a list and instead using : output.append("{0:<{1}} ".format(i, maxchars)), and then printing as print("".join(output)) right after the innermost for loop?